# text with outer stroke outline on iOS

Tags: ios, uilabel, stroke, outline

Android implements outline via outer stroke. So you can have a really thick outline that looks like this:

[image: Android thick outline]

iOS implements outline via inner stroke. So a thick outline will totally consume the inner color:

[image: iOS thick outline]

Is there any way to create an outer stroke effect on iOS?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1531/_index.html ? Also what attributes did you set to your NSAttributedString? Which values for the stroke?

Comment: This is not about how to create a text with stroke _and_ fill. This post is about the way iOS draws a stroke. It does this by drawing the stroke on the _inside_ of the characters (ie innner stroke). This way the fill color gets consumed if I use a really thick outline. In this context the set attributes is irellevant imho cause this move the discussion away from the algorithm used by iOS to how to configure the inner stroke. but for the sake of completenes: NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: -10; NSStrokeColorAttributeName:blackColor. What I want to know if it's possible to create an *outer* stroke

Comment: Sorry, misread, I though that the value (positive/negative) was helping to set the stroke inner/out. and that for the out, there was an "issue" with the fill color then

Comment: @P.Melch Have you found a solution?

Comment: @P.Melch Have you found a solution?

Comment: No. The results look vaguely similar but not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the same feature by using this lib:
https://github.com/tobihagemann/THLabel

However, I have to do more. If your label displays a complex attributed string with some attributes like underline, strike through, this lib will not help you to solve completely.

I've changed a bit in `draw(_:)` to only manually draw a filled image based on the main text shape that seems to look like an outer stroke.
https://github.com/dungntm58/THLabel/blob/swift/THLabel/THLabel.swift
Unfortunately, it does not work properly in some cases. I hope it will help you to solve your issue.

Edit: I updated my code to solve a lot of issues about label shadow, I think it will work perfectly.